# How to format the userId in Google Analytics script?

Tags: google-analytics, formatting, code-snippets, embedding

for my static HTML webside I embedded this recommended script code to every page of the side.

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-96597161-1', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');

ga('set', 'userId', {{USERID}});
```

The question is:
how to format my known Google analytics userId into this place `{{USERID}}`? 
Is it With brackets?, with quotes?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why not just try it out ?

Answer (score 1):

The [analytics.js fields reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#userId) lists UserID as format type "text", which means you pass it in like you would any other string value in Javascript (i.e. in as quoted string).

In fact the same page has examples:

```
// Set the user ID when creating the tracker.
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', {'userId': 'as8eknlll'});

// Alternatively, you may set the user ID via the `set` method.
ga('set', 'userId', 'as8eknlll');
```

Comment: Thank you @Elke Pierstoff. Can't bring it to run. I have to insert the script code to every page of the side, right? Not just to the home page, right?

Comment: Yes. And looking ar your code examples, you have to make sure the user id is set before the pageview tracking call, else it will have no effect.

Comment: Very nice @Elke Pierstoff. This line is moved now as the first of the three ga(..). Do I have to set up a Berichtsdatenansicht for every page of the side? Or just one Berichtsdatenansicht for the side?

Comment: Actually it need to go after the "create" and before the "send" (sorry, should have been more clear). You create an extra view and enable the UserId feature; this will work for the complete site that sends a userid, and will not track sessions that do not send the UserId.

Comment: Hi,@Elke Piersdoff. I moved this line as you described. Now it works for the home page. These very same lines of codes I have to add to each of the 10 pages of the site, right? And in Analytics there is no need to generate additional Datenansichten for the pages, right?

Comment: Yes. Code goes on all pages, and additional Views/Ansichten are necessary only if you want to filter the data in some way. Lunametrics has a few suggestions for filters anybody should have: http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2015/12/10/basic-google-analytics-filters/

Comment: Thank you Elke. I appreciate your friendly support.