# What is the recommended data format for the Google Analytics UserID?

Tags: google-analytics

I would like to know if the UserID can be set with Numerals or should it be text?
If it supports Text, can the text have spacing in the string?

For example `userID = "This Company Name" or should it be "This-Company-Name"?`

Is there a limit on the length of the UserID?

My question is similar to [How to format the userId in Google Analytics script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43324058/how-to-format-the-userid-in-google-analytics-script)

Comment: Both are valid, though I prefer to use dashes instead of spaces. Also note, userid should be unique, it shouldn't be a company name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be any string. Just take user id value from your database and paste it. 
I personally prefer to use alphanumeric only.

For uid field there no any length limitation, but if you want additionally to collet user id as a custom dimension, keep in mind that custom dimension length is limited to 150 bytes.